# How to display the pre-selected tags in the tag container from the tag container?

Tags: php, javascript, tags

I am working on a tag system, these tags have some specific colors. I want to add the pre-selected tags to the tagcontainer from the database, but it does not work.

mysql_result($result,0,"group_tag"):

```
<span class="label label-success">Male</span>,<span class="label label-success">Female</span>
```

For more information, you can also go to my previous question:

[Pass the information of tags to the php and display in another page( and can also update in another page)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298131/pass-the-information-of-tags-to-the-php-and-display-in-another-page-and-can-als)

and the jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/V9Euk/1015/

Here is the javascript code:

```
    $(function(){
    tags = new Array(<?php echo explode(',', mysql_result($result,0,"group_tag")); ?>);
    $('#edit_button').click(function(){
     $("#tag_handler").append(tags);
     });/*displays the tags already exists*/

    function add_tag(that){
      var tag = $(that).text();
      if($.inArray(tag, tags)>=0|| tags.length >= 10) return;
      tags.push(tag);
      var singleValues = $(that).find('span').clone();
      singleValues[0].innerHTML += "&times";
      $("#tag_handler").append(singleValues);/*display the selected tags in the tag_handler with &times style*/
}
      $(".fly li").click(function(){
       add_tag(this);
       });/*add tags to the tag_container when click the li*/

       $('#tag_handler').on('click', 'span', function(){
        var tag = $(this).text();
        var index = $.inArray(tag, tags);
        tags.splice(index,1);
        $(this).remove();
         });/*remove the tag when click this tag in the tag_container*/
        $('input#tags_selected').val(tags);
                                });
```

Comment: Just to clarify, your current code is what you've accomplished, but you'd like to basically just put the `#tagHandler` on another page?

Comment: Sorry, there are some pre-selected tags stored in the database, I want to display them in the #tagHandler and update them. Thanks

Comment: Is your goal to use it as a middle man to edit the database, or do you just want to have them loaded and edited temporarily?

Comment: I want to load them in tags = new Array(<?php echo explode(',', mysql_result($result,0,"group_tag")); and update them in the database after the user re-select the tags.

Comment: Thanks I gotcha, one minute.

Comment: Note: `mysql_*` is deprecated

Comment: I've included updated MySQL functionality in the example code.. Almost done btw

Comment: Why is it not deprecated? Because of secure reasons? @bystwn22

Comment: See this http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php‎

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/V9Euk/1016/